# ASP.NET core error handling error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I am starting to work on ASP.NET core error handling, and I noticed that I am getting an error in a format

```
{
    "errors": {},
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|caeb2316-47fb93bd8a17bc0a."
}
```

I am trying to get a more detailed error message, but I cannot get rid of this message.

I just followed instruction on *[Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1)*, but error is always there.

How can I get rid of this format of error message?

Comment: This response is the [standardized ProblemDetails response for APIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807). It is a good thing that you retrieve the error in this format. What more information would you want the response to contain? Usually, if you get “One or more validation errors occurred“, then the `errors` property should contain all the individual errors.

Comment: I was expecting a raw system error message. How can I remove this format in development stage and try to find a problem that is throwing this error message

Comment: _“find a problem that is throwing this error message”_ – This is a model validation problem. All the information is there in the response. And since this ProblemDetails object is only used for API controllers by default, you wouldn’t want this to cause a HTML-based response since your API clients likely cannot work with that.

Comment: Because this error message is not providing any error information, I am surprised you even ask this question. Validaton error without a detailed futher explanation or innerException is pretty vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below code you can create custom error response or custom problem details:

```
services.AddControllers()
 .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
 {
     o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
     {
         var problemsDetailsFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
             .GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
         var problemDetails = problemsDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(
             context.HttpContext, 
             context.ModelState);
         problemDetails.Detail = "Custom Details";
         problemDetails.Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
         problemDetails.Type = "https://tools.etf............";
         //problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity;
         problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
         problemDetails.Title = "One or more errors on input occured";
         return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails)
         {
             //ContentTypes= {"application/custom+json"}
         };
     };
 });
```

Comment: Hey Deepak. What is Implementation of  problemsDetailFactory?

Comment: @silversk8terz, you can ask your specific questions as a seperate question.